# What is the difference between itms-app:// and https:// App Store link

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm trying to create the link to App Store and I found many ways to do it.

1. Open App Store page in iTunes Store.

   ```
   let url  = URL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542")
   ```
2. Open App Store.

   ```
   let url  = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542")
   ```
3. Open App Store.

   ```
   let url  = URL(string: "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542?mt=8")
   ```

As far as I know, Method #2 and #3 almost produce the same result.

But I curious it should have some difference?.

Answer (score 3):

if you have using this link `itms-app://` it will open the app directly in the store.

```
let url  = URL(string: "itms://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542")
```

you have using this link `https://` it will open links from launching iTunes with Safari.

```
var iTunesLink = "https://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: iTunesLink)!)
```

Comment: was a bit confusing to me the first line has itms-app://  and the example below only itms://

Answer (score 1):

First of all `itms` and `itms-apps` are defined Apple URL Schemes and they are only linked immediately to their specific app as you said `itms` will open iTunes Store and `itms-apps` will open the App Store.(if they exist)

```
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:]) { (finished) in
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
```

Using `https` if used with `openURL` or `open` will launch the App Store if exist or iOS supported otherwise it will launch Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 depends on JavaScript. If you load `https://itunes.apple.com/th/app/cafe-amazon-smart-pay/id1047593542` in the browser with JavaScript disabled, the App Store won't open.